# PHP if else statement not executing code when value is true

Tags: php, if-statement

This is for a quiz application.

This is my comparison where $number is the question number and will increase every time the user submits an answer and we will assume $totalquestions = 3 for now as the category has only 3 questions.

I've echoed both values to make sure they are what I expect them to be and done var_dump($number == $totalQuestions); which returns true when $number = 3 but does not execute my code to redirect to the finish page once all questions are done and I have no clue why.

Any help would be great as I've been staring at this problem for hours!

```
<?php include('server.php'); ?>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['geoScore'])){
        $_SESSION['geoScore'] = 0;
    }

    //Get quiz category
    $activeCategoryID = (int) $_GET['c'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE CategoryID = $activeCategoryID";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $categoryName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $categoryName['CategoryName'];

    //Get question number
    $number = (int) $_GET['n'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE QuestionID = $number AND CategoryID = $activeCategoryID";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    //Get choices for question
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE QuestionID = $number";
    $choices = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    //Get total questions for category
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE CategoryID = $activeCategoryID";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $totalQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo $totalQuestions;
        echo $number;

        var_dump($number == $totalQuestions); // returns true because values are equal

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $correctChoice = $row['AnswerID'];

        echo $correctChoice;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $selectedChoice = $_POST['choice'];
        $next = $number+1;
        $activeCategory = $_POST['activeCategoryID'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE CategoryID = activeCategoryID";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $totalQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //Get correct choice
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE QuestionID = $number AND Correct = 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $correctChoice = $row['AnswerID'];

        if($correctChoice == $selectedChoice){
            $_SESSION['geoScore']++;
        }

        //Check to see if questions have finished
        if($number == $totalQuestions){
        header("Location: finish.php");
        }else{
        header("Location: geoQuiz.php?n=".$next."&c=".$activeCategory);
        }
    }
?>
```

**EDIT: Previous working version that did not dynamically get the quiz category**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['geoScore'])){
        $_SESSION['geoScore'] = 0;
    }

    //Get question number
    $number = (int) $_GET['n'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE QuestionID = $number AND CategoryID = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    //Get choices for question
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE QuestionID = $number";
    $choices = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    //Get total questions for category
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE CategoryID = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $totalQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $selectedChoice = $_POST['choice'];
        $next = $number+1;
        $_SESSION['activeCategory'] = "Geography";


        $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE CategoryID = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $totalQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        //Get correct choice
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE QuestionID = $number AND Correct = 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $correctChoice = $row['AnswerID'];

        echo $correctChoice;
        echo $selectedChoice;

        if($correctChoice == $selectedChoice){
            $_SESSION['geoScore']++;
        }


        echo $geoScore;

        //Check to see if questions have finished
        if($number == $totalQuestions){
        header("Location: finish.php");
        }else{
        header("Location: geoQuiz.php?n=".$next);
        }
    }

?>
```

The above code was my previous version which worked but I would needed to have had multiple php pages for each quiz category so I tried to change this to take the category using $_GET[] in the link from index page and it seems to all work apart from when the questions are finished and to head to finish.php

Comment: What you get in this $correctChoice?

Comment: `activeCategoryID` vs. `$activeCategory` in your `$query`??

Comment: try to put an `exit` after your redirect to stop all other instructions (if there are)

Comment: @Dipak Dholakiya it's the ID value of the answer which is correct for the current question

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: `$number = $_POST['number'];` is overwriting the value of `$number` which was previously populated from `$number = (int) $_GET['n'];`. So you might want to try running `var_dump($number == $totalQuestions);` a bit later in your code.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the heads up. This is my first real crack at php and MySQL for coursework so I don’t want to over complicate things and confuse myself for now and just get the basics down but I’ll certainly look into it